# FATAL: extension "timescaledb" must be preloaded HINT: Please preload the timescaledb library via shared_preload_libraries

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I’m getting an error during the Postgresql TimescaleDB setup.  Everything looks fine, I run `timescaledb-tune`, which seems to work just fine, but when I go into `psql` and run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;`, it prompts me to

> FATAL:  extension "timescaledb" must be preloaded HINT:  Please
> preload the timescaledb library via shared_preload_libraries.

**The thing is that I've added timescaledb to my shared_preload_libraries.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart Postgres after changing `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: Yes, but I’ve restarted the DB again to be sure.

Comment: What is the result from this SQL statement: SHOW shared_preload_libraries;

Comment: show shared_preload_libraries; I realized that does not include timescaledb.

Answer (score 3):

You need to browse into the `PostgreSQL` folder, open `postgresql.conf` and scroll down to

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'
```

That change will then require a restart of `psql` (or much better stop `postgres` and then start using it again).

[image: postgresql.conf screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Under the Windows system, if you've modified `shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'` in `postgresql.conf` as @AMarc mentioned, but it's still not working, please note that you need to restart postgresql service. The restart process is as follows:

1. Search for "Control Panel" in the Windows search bar.
2. Click on "Control Panel" to open it.
3. In the "Control Panel", search for "Administrative Tools" and click to enter.
4. Find "Services" and click to enter.
5. Look for the service starting with "p", locate "postgresql" service, and click on it.
6. On the left side, click on "Restart" to restart the "postgresql" service.

By following these steps, you will be able to successfully restart the postgresql service on Windows.